# How does kube-prometheus-stack implement HA with replicas?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, high-availability, prometheus-operator, kube-prometheus-stack

If we configure kube-prometheus-stack with replicas = 2, then two instances of Prometheus get running. However no Thanos Query is deployed for aggregation. Then how is the aggregation of data with deduplication is provided for these two instances by kube-prometheus-stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no aggregation or state sharing - what you are getting is basically two independent prometheuses, which are scrapping same targets. See https://prometheus-operator.dev/docs/operator/high-availability/

> The Prometheus instances scrape the same targets and evaluate the same rules, hence they will have the same data in memory and on disk, with a slight twist that given their different external label, the scrapes and evaluations won’t happen at exactly the same time. As a consequence, query requests executed against each Prometheus instance may return slightly different results.

Deduplication of alerts is happening on AlertManager side. So having two or more prometheuses provides only high availability, and not scaling.

> Running multiple Prometheus instances avoids having a single point of failure but it doesn’t help scaling out Prometheus in case a single Prometheus instance can’t handle all the targets and rules.

As for using Grafana or any other visualization tool - you should configure sticky sessions, to query single instance at a time

> For dashboarding, sticky sessions (using sessionAffinity on the Kubernetes Service) should be used, to get consistent graphs when refreshing or you can use something like Thanos Querier to federate the data.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out and clarifying. It also looks like in AWS EKS the stack creates the two Prometheus replicas across different availability zones - is this implemented intentionally in the stack or happens accidentally? In case of redeployment of the stack it picks up the EBS storage left from previous deployment and redeploys in the same AZs where EBS storage was left by the previous deployment - I suppose this is also done by design by the stack?

Comment: I don't use aws, so i can't comment on that, but it totally makes sense - you get two replicas in different AZs with same-ish data (since each Prometheus scrapes it's own data), a redeployment of (same, i guess?) monitoring infrastructure reuses same TSDB files. There is no point in high availability in same AZ - by design it is likely to go down as a whole, so each prometheus replica should reside in different AZ